# mysql query to fetch records for each given key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates

I am trying to fetch record for each given id using mysql select query.
Eg.

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM employee 
WHERE (emp_id) IN (212,213,312,212,213,414,515);
```

I get result as below -

```
Name
A
B
C
D
E
```

I need BELOW output like-

```
NAME
A
B
C
A
B
D
E
```

Any idea?

Comment: How is the list of `emp_id` values being built?

Comment: Consider handling display issues in application code

Comment: Do you have some other processing between the select and the display? Looks like the de-duplication is there, not in the actual SQL.

Comment: I have list of users who are frequent traveler , so there are multiple entry for the same users , for which I have got the list of the  ids against which there are other dependent data . Hence need the output in this way.

Answer (score 4):

You have duplicates in the `IN` list that you want duplicated in the results.  `WHERE` clauses do not multiply the number of rows, they simply filter.  Another approach is `JOIN`, but you need a table of values.

So, construct one:

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM employee JOIN
     (SELECT 212 as emp_id, 1 as ord UNION ALL
      SELECT 213 as emp_id, 2 as ord UNION ALL
      SELECT 312 as emp_id, 3 as ord UNION ALL
      SELECT 212 as emp_id, 4 as ord UNION ALL
      SELECT 213 as emp_id, 5 as ord UNION ALL
      SELECT 414 as emp_id, 6 as ord UNION ALL
      SELECT 515 as emp_id, 7 as ord
     ) v
     USING (emp_id)
ORDER BY v.ord;
```

I notice that you want to maintain the ordering.  A SQL result set is *unordered* unless you explicitly use `ORDER BY`.